# REP-1216 | print condition error

Tags: oracle, reportbuilder

i face this problem in oracle Report Builder REP-1216
anybody can explain ??

Answer (score 0):

From the Reports Builder on-line help:

> **Cause:**
>
> You set an invalid Print Condition for
>   the specified object. For example, you
>   might have tried to set the Print
>   Condition of a margin object.
>
> **Action:**
>
> Change the Print Condition of the
>   object to another, valid setting.

Does that help?  Does the message indicate which object has the invalid condition?

Comment: What if it does indicate the object...what should we do ?